# RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : object is not a managed entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-repositories

Scenario:

SpringBoot Executor:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "io.sciro.leaderdata.domain")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"io.sciro.leaderdata.config", "io.sciro.leaderdata.repo", "io.sciro.leaderdata.domain", "io.sciro.leaderdata.controller"})
public class LeaderDataApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LeaderDataApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Data
@NodeEntity(label = "match")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = JSOGGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Match implements IdStrategy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String codeName;
    private Long round;
    private String me;
    private String pc;
    private Character result;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm:ss a")
    private Date timestamp;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm:ss a")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastUpdated;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm:ss a")
    @CreatedDate
    private Date created;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Match{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", codeName='" + codeName + '\'' +
                ", round=" + round +
                ", me='" + me + '\'' +
                ", pc='" + pc + '\'' +
                ", result=" + result +
                ", timestamp=" + timestamp +
                ", lastUpdated=" + lastUpdated +
                ", created=" + created +
                '}';
    }

    /**
     * Generates new id for given entity
     *
     * @param entity saved entity
     * @return identifier of the entity
     */
    @Override
    public Object generateId(Object entity) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Repo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "matches", collectionResourceRel = "matches")
public interface MatchRepo extends Neo4jRepository<Match, Long> {
    Collection<Match> findAllByCodeName(@Param("codeName") String codeName);
}
```

Config-Classes. One for Live & the other for Dev/Test.

```
@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "io.sciro.leaderdata.repo")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "io.sciro.leaderdata.domain")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DevConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DevConfig.class);

    //Values Injected in the Live-Config: @Value("${spring.data.neo4j.uri}")
    private final String uri = "bolt://localhost:7687";
    private final String username = "neo4j";
    private final String password = "password";

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        // with domain entity base package(s)
        return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "io.db.accountservice.domain");
    }

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
        LOGGER.debug("URI: \n\n\nuri: {}\n\n\n", uri);
        return new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration
                .Builder()
                .uri(uri)
                .credentials(username, password)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

}
```

When the SpringBoot Application is in execution, I do a curl I get positive responses:

Post via unix-terminal:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"codeName":"Test-CodeName-1","round":1,"me":"ROCK","pc":"ROCK","result":"D","lastUpdated":"Nov 19, 2018, 9:44:11 PM","created":"Nov 19, 2018, 9:44:11 PM"}' http://localhost:8003/spring-data/api/v1/matches
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 
Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Nov 2018 09:44:11 GMT
Location: http://localhost:8003/spring-data/api/v1/matches/2
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 20 Nov 2018 08:52:52 GMT

{
  "id" : "1",
  "codeName" : "Test-CodeName-1",
  "round" : 1,
  "me" : "ROCK",
  "pc" : "ROCK",
  "result" : "D",
  "timestamp" : null,
  "lastUpdated" : "Nov 19, 2018, 09:44:11 AM",
  "created" : "Nov 19, 2018, 09:44:11 AM",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8003/spring-data/api/v1/matches/2"
    },
    "match" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8003/spring-data/api/v1/matches/2"
    }
  }
}%
```

Get via UNIX-terminal:

```
curl -i -X GET http://localhost:8003/spring-data/api/v1/matches/2
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Nov 2018 09:44:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 20 Nov 2018 11:19:14 GMT

{
  "id" : "1",
  "codeName" : "Test-CodeName-1",
  "round" : 1,
  "me" : "ROCK",
  "pc" : "ROCK",
  "result" : "D",
  "timestamp" : null,
  "lastUpdated" : "Nov 19, 2018, 09:44:11 AM",
  "created" : "Nov 19, 2018, 09:44:11 AM",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8003/spring-data/api/v1/matches/2"
    },
    "match" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8003/spring-data/api/v1/matches/2"
    }
  }
}%
```

Test Case:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@WebAppConfiguration(value = "classpath:bootstrap.yml")
@SpringBootTest(classes = LeaderDataApp.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class MatchRepoTest {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MatchRepoTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private static final String TEST_NAME = "Test-CodeName-1";

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup(){
        LOGGER.info("Testing MatchRepo...");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void teardown(){
        LOGGER.info("Completed MatchRepo tests...");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void matchRepoTest_1_saveNewMatch() throws Exception {
        final Date date = new Date();
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        final Match match = new Match();
        match.setCodeName(TEST_NAME);
        match.setCreated(date);
        match.setLastUpdated(date);
        match.setMe("ROCK");
        match.setPc("ROCK");
        match.setResult('D');
        match.setRound(1L);


        final String payload = gson.toJson(match);

        LOGGER.debug("Match: "+ payload);
// {"codeName":"Test-CodeName-1","round":1,"me":"ROCK","pc":"ROCK","result":"D","lastUpdated":"Nov 19, 2018, 9:44:11 PM","created":"Nov 19, 2018, 9:44:11 PM"}
        mockMvc.perform(post(APP_BASE_URL+"/matches")
                .content(payload)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }

    @Test
    public void matchRepoTest_2_findById() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get(APP_BASE_URL+"/matches/20")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$.codeName", is(TEST_NAME)));
    }
}
```

And now the challenge comes in when I try to execute my Integration-Tests using Jupiter. My tests fail with a bizarre stacktrace that doesn't mean much to me. Error Message:

```
"Class class io.sciro.leaderdata.domain.Match is not a valid entity class. Please check the entity mapping."
```

Doesn't mean much. Anyone else knows what that means?

```
2018-11-20 02:48:36.377  INFO 18036 --- [           main] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2018-11-20 02:48:36.377  INFO 18036 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2018-11-20 02:48:36.393  INFO 18036 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 16 ms
2018-11-20 02:48:36.599  INFO 18036 --- [           main] Driver                                   : Driver instance org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver@620992a8 created
2018-11-20 02:48:36.972 ERROR 18036 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : Class class io.sciro.leaderdata.domain.Match is not a valid entity class. Please check the entity mapping.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class class io.sciro.leaderdata.domain.Match is not a valid entity class. Please check the entity mapping.
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:97) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:46) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:463) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedSessionCreator.java:122) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SimpleNeo4jRepository.save(SimpleNeo4jRepository.java:72) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.CrudRepositoryInvoker.invokeSave(CrudRepositoryInvoker.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeSave(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:176) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.createAndReturn(RepositoryEntityController.java:480) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:272) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998) [spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875) [spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at io.sciro.leaderdata.repo.MatchRepoTest.matchRepoTest_1_saveNewMatch(MatchRepoTest.java:101) [classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:515) [junit-platform-commons-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:105) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1378) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1378) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]

2018-11-20 02:48:36.987  WARN 18036 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class class io.sciro.leaderdata.domain.Match is not a valid entity class. Please check the entity mapping.]

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /spring-data/api/v1/matches
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController
           Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 500
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"cause":null,"message":"Class class io.sciro.leaderdata.domain.Match is not a valid entity class. Please check the entity mapping."}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<500>
Expected :201
Actual   :500
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:55)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:619)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:195)
    at io.sciro.leaderdata.repo.MatchRepoTest.matchRepoTest_1_saveNewMatch(MatchRepoTest.java:104)
```

Comment: try to add @DataJpaTest to your test class

Comment: I just read the spec on '@DataJpaTest': By default, tests annotated with '@DataJpaTest' will use an embedded in-memory database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured DataSource). Which is not what I want to do.

@slimane Just tried it: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/ConnectionCallback. I think the problem lies in the entity/domain (Match class). I think I am missing something there, based on the stacktrace.

Comment: do you have @EnableJpaRepositories("package to your repos") somewhere in your configuration?

Comment: @slimane Yes, I have '@EnableNeo4jRepositories' instead, since I'm not using JPA. I'm using  Neo4J NoSql DB. I forgot to add that config class in the original question/post. let me update it in the original post. Thx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. In my config class, the second parameter in the SessionFactory argument was incorrect:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    // with domain entity base package(s)
    return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "io.db.accountservice.domain");
}
```

It was supposed to be:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    // with domain entity base package(s)
    return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "io.sciro.leaderdata.domain");
}
```